# foreach select node xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get signation from each entree using foreach select = commandes/commande

```
<root>
<commandes>
    <commande date="2012-12-05" numero="c1001">
        <entree ref="p1012732NC" prix="39.98" quantite="2" />
        <entree ref="p2203633" prix="149" quantite="1" />
        <entree ref="p2103625E" prix="249" quantite="1" />
        <entree ref="p3317" prix="325" quantite="2" />
    </commande>
    <commande date="2012-12-06" numero="c1002">
        <entree ref="p22651-02" prix="99.99" quantite="3" />
        <entree ref="p2212807DE" prix="79.98" quantite="2" />
        <entree ref="p5418151" prix="129" quantite="1" />
    </commande>
</commandes>
<produits>
    <produit type="chemise" promo="no">
        <reference>p1012732NC</reference>
        <signation>CHEMISE MARCO FERRERA</signation>
        <prixNormal>39.98</prixNormal>
        <prixPromo/>
        <image>w10-1012732nc-tq.jpg</image>
    </produit>
</produits>
</root>
```

MY XSL :

```
<xsl:template match="/catalogue">
  <xsl:for-each select="commandes/commande">
    <xsl:value-of select="idref(@ref)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I do that with xsl?

Comment: Have you tried solving the problem yourself? Can you show your XSLT up to now?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "I want to get signation". Please state more clearly what output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to read up on **xsl:key** here, as this is what you can use to look up values from other nodes. It looks like you want to look up the **produit** element based on its **reference**. In this case, you would define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="idref" match="produit" use="reference" />
```

Then to call it for a specific reference, you would do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('idref', 'p1012732NC')" />
```

This would return the **produit** element. If you wanted the **signation** value, you would do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('idref', 'p1012732NC')/signation" />
```

More usually, you would call it using a value of an existing element or attribute. In your case, it looks like the **ref** attribute on the **entree** element is what you would use. Therefore your code would look like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="commandes/commande/entree">
   <xsl:value-of select="key('idref', @ref)/signation"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```